# Import/export google mail (was "[is it possible to] create custom Google Lab")

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to create a custom Google Lab project?  Or do Google Engineers have to create them?  I'd like to integrate Gmail with another web application on a company web server.

If that is not possible, is there a way to import/export google mail in some format (ie: XML, HTML, etc..) for a specific gmail user or group of gmail users?

Comment: you cant actually add to the google labs projects...but google provides its api to users through their service called google apps...there's free services and paid services ...gmail is one of their many services for companies

Comment: can you import/export gmail using google apps?

Comment: you're probably looking at SLaks answer there, you can import your import email through IMAP, what exactly are you trying to do? if you wish to integrate gmail w/ your company, google apps should suffice...they allow you to sync with blackberry enterprise servers or microsoft outlook clients...here is their list of services specifically for gmail: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/features.html

Comment: just doing some integration for our issue Agile application to track conversations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You're looking for the IMAP protocol, which allows you to interact with Gmail messages.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. Google Labs projects are Google's own experiments, not something you can add to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As Nadir Muzaffar  said, maybe Gmail's API is what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Comment: Since this is your fist answer/response to a question you should take note of the length and thoroughness of  accepted answers  in drafting your own. What you have written here is more of a comment than an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that you may create a browser extension.
You may start with experimenting with Developer toolbar (F12) and then pack your javascript to an extension.

If you use I.E. Chrome, see I.E. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension or try to look at your current extensions in order to understand how it's working ( ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/ or ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/ )

Note that if GMail changes, your extension may not work anymore.